# UndoManager and multiple MOC

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data, nsmanagedobjectcontext, nsundomanager

I have 3 MOC.

1. MainThread MOC to display stuff (with undomanager)
2. Background-save MOC to save data to disc (connected to store)
3. Backgorund-update MOC to download data from server, parse it and save later

They are parent-child relation.

1. Background-update -> 1. MainThread -> 2. Background-save (store)

Now when I download data from background I need to disable undomanager on mainthread so they are not undo - that can be a case that user is editing something at the same time.

Now question is if that is correct. I have that code in background-update thread

```
 //create child background context which is child of 1. MainThread
 NSManagedObjectContext* context = [[AppManager sharedAppManager] createChildManagedObjectContext];
 //I'M DOING ALL CHANGES ON DATA HERE
 [context.parentContext.undoManager disableUndoRegistration]; //disable undo on main thread
 [context save:nil]; //save changes to background thread
 [context.parentContext save:nil]; //save changes to main thread
 [context.parentContext processPendingChanges]; //process changes on main thread
 [context.parentContext.parentContext save:nil]; //save data to disc on 3. save-thread
 [context.parentContext.undoManager enableUndoRegistration]; //enable undo again
```

With blocks it looks like that:

```
[context.parentContext performBlockAndWait:^{
            [context.parentContext.undoManager disableUndoRegistration];

            [context performBlockAndWait:^{
                [context save:nil];
            }];

            [context.parentContext save:nil];
            [context.parentContext processPendingChanges];

            [context.parentContext performBlockAndWait:^{
                [context.parentContext.parentContext save:nil];
            }];

            [context.parentContext.undoManager enableUndoRegistration];
        }];
```

I'm asking because occasionally I'm getting some inconsistency crashes and I cannot really find a reason for those.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, some basic observations about the posted code.

1. You should only user `performBlockAndWait` when absolutely necessary... which is almost never.
2. You are calling `performBlockAndWait` on a child context, while inside `performBlockAndWait` on the parent context.  You should **never** do that.
3. Using `performBlockAndWait` to call `save:` on a context that has a patent context is almost guaranteed to not do what you think it does.  All it does is save up to the parent context.
4. You are calling `performBlockAndWait` while inside a `performBlockAndWait` on the same context.  Nothing wrong with that since that call is reentrant.  However, it is another clue that there is something wrong with your CD stack management.

Now, some suggestions that may help.

In your situation, I would suggest a change to your MOC hierarchy.  Keep the private queue MOC as a parent to the main queue MOC.  That allows your DB changes to be done asynchronously.  Nothing wrong there.  Just remember that you have to cascade the `save:` call to the parent or schedule a save because saving the main MOC will only copy its data up the stack to the parent context, and will not touch the underlying database.

However, I would take that background MOC and remove it as a child of the main MOC.  Now, you don't have to worry about the undo manager at all, you can leave it alone.

Speaking of the undo manager, I have found that the best undo manager is a child context.  I would just create a context that is a child of the main context, do all my changes in there.  If the changes are abandoned, just delete the context.  Everything is undone.  You can install an undo manager on that context for incremental undo management.

Now, how to handle that background context that is doing some type of asynchronous updates (probably from some web service).  I suggest either:

1. Set it's parent to be the same as the main MOC.  You will need to refresh the main MOC for changes to the parent.  This has the drawback that any updates to the database are synchronized through the same parent MOC, leaving more opportunity for the main MOC to wait while fetching.
2. Connect it directly to the persistent store coordinator, and use notifications to merge the changes.

Finally, revisit your design and see if you can get by with asynchronous calls.  You really should be able to get away with calling `performBlock` and only call `performBlockAndWait` in extremely rare situations.

Comment: Hey thanks for all tips. I'm using performBlockAndWait due to some crashes that I was able to produce during stress testing the app. Doing an update in background while stress testing EDIT / SAVE on main thread. With performBlock UndoManager was getting into some unstable state and crashes during that process. I will read through your comment and rethink my solution according to your suggestions - I probably will have some questions regarding that, but need to analyze it first :)

Comment: If `performBlockAndWait` is preventing crashes... that means you have synchronization issues in other areas that can probably be solved without blocking operations.

Comment: Accepting answer - took me a while to find solution, but I ended up throwing away undomanager and doing stuff on separate context which I throw away if user cancels. That solved most of my problems, thx for idea.